# How to conditionally select a row in rich:extendedDataTable

Tags: richfaces, jsf-2.2, selectionchanged

I am using the Richfaces 4.3.7 extendedDataTable to select an element and display its detail.
One of my requirements is to check if the user may lose some not recorded information before displaying the detail of the selection.
Actually, I am using this code:

```
<rich:extendedDataTable id="resultsTable" value="#{listMngr.model}" var="user" 
        selection="#{listMngr.selection}"
        iterationStatusVar="status" selectionMode="single" noDataLabel="#{labels['no.data.found']}"
        rows="#{listMngr.model.rowCount}">
    <a4j:ajax execute="@this"
        event="selectionchange"
        listener="#{listMngr.onSelectRow}" 
        render="#{rich:clientId('details')} #{rich:clientId('actions')}" 
        limitRender="true"/>
    <rich:column ...
```

In any case, when I come back from the `onSelectRow`, the new row appears as selected and I lose the previous one. Is there a way to tell to the table that it should not change the selected row?

Comment: Why can't you do the check before the selection?

Comment: Probably because I don't know how I can do it? And then how I will be able to indicate that the new row must be selected (which is a step later)?